# Google Analytics PageView with multiple Fragments

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I have an Android app that has a fragment with a list of items, and another fragment with the detail of this item.

My app presents 1 fragment each time on smartphone screens, and 2 fragments at same time on tablet screens. Like this:
[image: Fragments on smartphone and tablet]

So, I am using Google Analytics to track pageviews in my List Fragment and Detail Fragment. It works perfectly on smartphones, because track 1 pageview each time.

But how can I track PageViews of both List and Detail fragments on tablets?